# How to install simplegui using terminal?

Tags: command-line, python, sudo, gnome-terminal

I am currently learning Python at Coursera, where we use [simpleGUI](http://www.codeskulptor.org/) (Hit play on top left) to creat intractive games.

So, I wanted to use it on my machine. I found [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QDazgiXakc) installing simpleGUI through terminal using following command:

`sudo apt-get install python-tk`

`easy_install simplegui`

But it is not working on my computer.

Comment: Any errors ????

Comment: @markkirby using `simple_install` it says it is not installed try `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools'. On trying again after that it shows following message `[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-8242.write-test'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Then

```
sudo easy_install simplegui
```

You don't have permission to write to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/test-easy-install-8242.write-test it is owned by root.